# brew update: failure while executing: git pull --ff --no-rebase --quiet origin

Tags: homebrew

I am on a computer at work that has been used by somebody else for the past 4 years. I have no idea how often updated brew. The computer is mostly used for running C jobs.

I did

```
brew update
```

and the following came out

```
error: unable to unlink old '.travis.yml' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'CONTRIBUTING.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'README.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'SUPPORTERS.md' (Permission denied)
Error: Failure while executing: git pull --ff --no-rebase --quiet origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run "brew doctor", but it probably would be better to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Uninstall ([directions](http://superuser.com/questions/203707/how-to-uninstall-homebrew-mac-os-x-package-manager)) and reinstall solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error output has your answer. The permissions of those files need to be fixed. They are likely owned by root and not accessible to `brew update` when run as your user. `sudo chown <your_username> <file_name>` and you should be able to update brew.

Sure, uninstalling and reinstalling works, but it's sometimes nice to resolve things before going that route.